# Unable to create hyperlink after Wordpress updated

Tags: links, visual-editor

I am recently facing an important issue. This issue happened after an updates completed. The issue i facing is, the visual editor was not responding when i creating links with the `Insert/Edit Link` button. In other words, i unable to create link with the visual editor. I have to create the link by html source. It's such troublesome if i have to go on doing this way.

Do you guys facing same issue as well? Is there any solution to fix this issue?

Comment: How is it not working? Does the button do literally nothing when pressed? Have you tried disabling plugins to see if some of them affect that? Seems to work fine on my update :/

Comment: The dialog of creating link was able to open. It is just don't work after i entered the link i want to create. The function was fine before the update. I have never installed other plugin after this updates. So, i'm wondering why this would happen. @jimihenrik.

Comment: @jimihenrik, an updates to this question. This issue has been resolved after an existing plugin updated. Thanks!

Comment: Good to hear you got it sorted!